# AngularJS - Event fired only once

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast

I've got this in a first controller : (executed on ng-mouseover)

```
$scope.overMenu = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('overMenu');
    console.log('overMenu');
};
```

And this in a second one :

```
$scope.$on('overMenu', $scope.overMenu());
$scope.overMenu = function()
{
    console.log('on overMenu');
    //gridLayoutPlugin.updateGridLayout();
};
```

But my event is fired or catched only once and i don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !

I started over everything and putting my $scope.$on at the end of my controller, i don't remember but maybe i declared it before the function i wanted to call...

Answer (score 0):

Event handler should be a function reference:

```
$scope.$on('overMenu', $scope.overMenu);
```

When you put parentheses after function name you immediately invoke it. What you want to do is to provide a reference to a function to be called on once event occures.

Comment: hi, even when i try this : 
    $scope.$on('overMenu', console.log('on overMenu'));
it still works only once.